# Why does an integer x have an inverse y if and only if x is coprime to n where x*y=1 (mod n)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, modular-arithmetic

Let us say we are given the integer x and the modulus n {x<n}. We have to prove that:

For the integer x there exists an integer y {y<n} such that x*y=1 (mod n) <=> x is coprime to n.

(I)

Let us say that for the integer x there exists an integer y such that x*y=1 (mod n) => x*y-1=0 (mod n) => x*y-1=k*n (for some integer k) => x*y-k*n=1
Let us say that there exists an integer d>=1 such that d|x and d|n => d|(x*y-k*n) => d|1;
But then d must be 1 and the gcd(x,n)=1 because it would be the only common factor since d divides both x and n. So, x and n are coprime.

(II)

Let us say that x and n are coprime <=> gcd(x,n)=1. Then, by bezout lemma, there exist integers a,b such that x*a+n*b=gcd(x,n)=1. But then looking at the equation (mod n) it gets:

x*a=1 (mod n) => for the integer x there exists an integer a=y such that the statement x*y=1 (mod n) is satisfied.

Could you please confirm if it is a valid proof or have I made any mistakes?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: For a `solution-verification` question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be an open-ended proof checking machine.